# Ripped plastic Canadian currency/bills

Tags: canada, currency

Can a ripped Canadian Plastic Bill with 60% portion of the bill remaining containing both serial #s still get full value?

Answer (score 7):

You can read about the procedure for requesting reimbursement for mutilated Canadian currency, the [Bank of Canada's Bank Note Redemption Service](https://www.bankofcanada.ca/banknotes/bank-note-redemption-service/).  However, they do not seem to give any specifics about how they determine whether a bank note is eligible for reimbursement or not, so it may be a case-by-case decision.

> **Mutilated bank notes**
>
> Mutilated bank notes show signs of excessive damage from fire or water, missing pieces, or other forms of deterioration.

> These bank notes are likely too damaged or brittle to be used for payment, so you can send them to us for redemption. **We will examine them to determine the value of your claim.**

But it seems like you might as well try it - you just have to fill out a brief form and mail it in with the banknote.  If the Bank of Canada won't reimburse it, presumably nobody else would either.

Answer (score -1):

Yeah just (if it's ripped in half) tape it back together and go to your bank of choice and ask them to replace, it they will do it as long as it's more than 3/5 fine

Comment: [citation needed]